# Why is Response.Write not binding?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm stuck with code that is failing to bind. It's not using SQL, it's just a simple form using `Response.Write` in the codebehind.

Here's the code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        'Populate DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("fname")
        dt.Columns.Add("lname")
        dt.Rows.Add()
        dt.Rows(0)("fname") = Response.ContentType = "fname"
        dt.Rows(0)("lname") = Response.ContentType = "lname"

        'Bind Datatable to Labels
        lblfname.Text = dt.Rows(0)("fname").ToString()
        lbllname.Text = dt.Rows(0)("lname").ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you creating a `DataTable` at all if you're just setting text from it? And why are you setting `Response.ContentType` in there? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet In C# that line would be `dt.Rows[0]["fname"] = (Response.ContentType == "fname")`.

Comment: @GSerg: Right, missed that. It's still a very strange thing to do. I suspect that `Response.ContentType` doesn't really mean what the OP expects it to mean.

Comment: Response.ContentType holds  [Media types (formerly called MIME types)](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).  DataTables are not so much "bound" as filled with data from a datastore.  Certain Asp.Net Server Controls (like GridView) are Bound.  e.g you could Fill a DataTable and then Bind it to a GridView